# Can we use pm2 to start the development server of Vue cli?

Tags: vue.js, yarnpkg, pm2

After creating a Vue project using vue cli, we can run it using

```
yarn run serve
```

I am not able to start using pm2. Running

```
pm2 start yarn -- run serve
```

I got a few crash-and-restart, after that, pm2 will stop to try to restart. 
In the log I can see

```
C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\YARN\BIN\YARN.CMD:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { @echo off
                                                              ^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Utente\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\lib\ProcessContainerFork.js:27:21)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
```

I am running the pm2 command from the root of my project, where running `yarn run serve` works without problem

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### My solution

First, deleted all running pm2 instances

```
pm2 delete all
```

Then entered this configuration as `ecosystem.js`

```
module.exports = {
  apps: [
    {
      name: "WEB",
      script: "./node_modules/@vue/cli-service/bin/vue-cli-service.js",
      args: "serve"
    }
  ]
};
```

> Note: vue server is already setup natively to do watching and reloading so do not add watch to pm2 settings otherwise the full dev server will be restarted, instead of doing the plain hot reload of vue-cli-service
>
> Also: I suggest to install pm2-logrotate

Then restarted

```
pm2 start ecosystem.js
```

To follow logs simply use

```
pm2 logs
```

eventually adding the app name as argument to see only one log

### Use case

I'm using this to work on a local smtp-catcher server and a webapp to read the catched email

Comment: This worked, thanks. I just changed the command a little bit, instead i am doing: 

pm2 start "/var/www/html/myapp/node_modules/.bin/vue-cli-service serve" --name “App Node JS"

This way it worked - But is it a good practice? Is this the correct way to execute Vue server?

Answer (score 4):

Yes you can. `pm2 start "npm run serve" --name <app name here>`

Comment: This didnt work.

Comment: Did you run the command with the app name as specified in package.json?...N.B: I did not generate the ecosystem file. I just ran the command as is.

Comment: Yes... I did run with the name specified in package,json but it didnt recognized.

Comment: This worked perfectly, my command was pm2 start "npm run dev -- --host" --name <app name as mentioned in package.json>